# FullCalendar TypeError: $(…).fullCalendar is not a function with prod profile

Tags: angular, fullcalendar, jhipster

I build my jhipster project using prod profile and after this i have the error as in description in the following component in Angular 4:

```
    import { Component, ViewChild, Input, Output, ElementRef, EventEmitter, AfterViewInit } from '@angular/core';
import 'fullcalendar/dist/fullcalendar.js';
import * as jQuery from 'jquery';

@Component({
    selector: 'ba-full-calendar',
    templateUrl: 'ba-full-calendar.component.html'
})
export class BaFullCalendar implements AfterViewInit {

    @Input() baFullCalendarConfiguration: Object;
    @Input() baFullCalendarClass: string;
    @Output() onCalendarReady = new EventEmitter<any>();

    @ViewChild('baFullCalendar') public _selector: ElementRef;

    ngAfterViewInit() {
        const calendar = jQuery(this._selector.nativeElement).fullCalendar(this.baFullCalendarConfiguration);
        this.onCalendarReady.emit(calendar);
    }
}
```

i think is something related to prod profile because i don't have the same issue with dev profile.
In the webpack.common.ts i added:

```
 new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
                "$": "jquery",
                "jQuery": "jquery",
                "window.jQuery":"jquery"
            }),
```

I'm using the gateway app from jhipster.

Comment: Have you modified webpack config for jquery? https://github.com/gdi2290/angular-starter/wiki/How-to-include-jQuery Also, it's usually not recommended to mix jquery and angular. When you can, you should prefer components that do not depend on JQuery.

Comment: i have already in webpack.common.js:  new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
                "$": "jquery",
                "jQuery": "jquery",
                "window.jQuery":"jquery"
            }),

Comment: And you have also added it to vendor.ts as documented in your project's README?  Please edit your question with these important details.

Comment: No, i didn't. What i have to add?

Comment: I understood everything, so i'm only trying to explain that with profile dev it works and it doesn't with prod profile. i would like to know the reason, so if you wanna help me i will be glad.

Comment: prod build is very different from dev build due to template compilation, AOT and tree-shaking to remove unused dependencies. This last one is probably the cause of your issue and this is why to help webpack you must import your deps in vendor.ts as the example about leaflet which was supposed to be generated in your README but maybe is missing. See https://github.com/jhipster/jhipster-sample-app/blob/8292ca7dcfcc458a9067f30db4413aebebac311a/src/main/webapp/app/layouts/profiles/profile-info.model.ts

Comment: I did as described in README but i have the same error :(